# simple sql query

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am getting an  error in this query  like incorrect syntax near  distinct statement

```
DECLARE  @CNT INT
SELECT @CNT= DISTINCT ISNULL(Employee.id,0)
FROM Employee 
WHERE EMPLOYEE.NAME='KIRAN'
```

**is there   anything  wrong in syntax**

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ISNULL(Employee.id,0)
FROM Employee 
WHERE EMPLOYEE.NAME='KIRAN'
```

**this  statements  works  fine**

thanks
prince

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe ..

```
DECLARE  @CNT INT
SET @CNT = (SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(Employee.id,0)
FROM Employee 
WHERE EMPLOYEE.NAME='KIRAN')
```

Comment: than you have a problem .. but that wasn't the question

Comment: the Query  returns  same value even  for  multiple  row values

Answer (score 0):

**1.use must write distinct before @CNT variable


2.select only first row because @cnt not table variable it is variable which type is int**

```
DECLARE  @CNT INT
SELECT top 1 @CNT= ISNULL(Employee.id,0)
FROM Employee 
WHERE EMPLOYEE.NAME='KIRAN'
```

you  can test it simply

```
declare @CNT INT

SELECT top 1 @CNT= ISNULL(Employee.id,0)
FROM Employee 
WHERE EMPLOYEE.NAME='KIRAN'

select @CNT
```